# my dart code is not running in android simulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

[I open my android emlator
and start to run dart code
I heard it's a pretty long process; so I waited
i waited for like 5-6 hours but the code is still not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATFxa.png)

Comment: It's not any problem from our side because in screenshot apk is installing in the emulator. after install apk you can see the app. but it's taking time then it's another problem in android studio. Could you please use another emulator for run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try "Invalidate Caches/Restart" in Android Studio?
I had a few times a similar case with installation over 5 min. This always helped